# How to Sort a Table with restrictions in cells?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a Table that needs to be sorted by the heading-names.
Now before I even create the file, I do a RestrictInput in the Template file, so the user only has limited input in certain cells.

Validation code:

```
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L9:L" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

 ' n.i.O. , i.O. Dropdown restriction
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="i.O,n.i.O."
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Now when trying to sort the table later, the fields with the ValidateList stay the same but the sort still applies. That is an issue, because people cannot enter anything else in exactly those fields where the whole row changed.

[image]

How do I enable filtering without including VBA in the result file?

If impossible. How do I call the Validation Function again on filter of any header?

Comment: You are hard coding "i.O,n.i.O" - how do you expect this to be changed without coding? What you can do is refer to a range - but that has to get sorted as well ...

Comment: @Ike Is there any other way to do it without hardcoding instead then?

Comment: As I said: put the lists on a sheet - but - to be honest - I don't get the basic issue "because people cannot enter anything else in exactly those fields where the whole row changed". A validation list limits the allowed input - this is independant of the sorting - I would guess.

Comment: That is the issue. When validation would be dependant of sorting, I would not have an issue with the cell entries, as everything would shift as intended on a sort.